# Reasoner not returning instances

Tags: java, ontology, owl

When I'm doing this, its not working

```
OWLClassExpression query = factory.getOWLObjectIntersectionOf(factory.getOWLClass("#belgique", pm))
```

reasoner.getInstances(query,true);

this one is working:

```
reasoner.getInstances(factory.getOWLClass("#belgique", pm),true);
```

But the thing is that i need to objectintersectionof because i need instances which are of several type of classes

I even tried this:

```
OWLClass newName = factory.getOWLClass(IRI.create("temp001"));
OWLAxiom definition = factory.getOWLEquivalentClassesAxiom(newName, query);
manager.addAxiom(ontology, definition);
reasoner.getInstances(newName,true)
```

its still not working

Answer (score 0):

`getOWLObjectIntersectionOf` is a way to build more complicated class expressions, the method asserts `and` relations between the input expressions, it's usually not used alone like this ([see there for backgroud](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-primer/#Complex_Classes)).

Example:

`Mother = ObjectIntersectionOf(Woman, Parent)`

A `Mother` here is defined as something that is a `Woman` **and** a `Parent`. The **and** is the object intersection.

You don't have to use it to retrieve instances of a class. In your case using `getOWLClass()` should do the job.

Comment: Suppose i want to get all instances which are ("Person" AND "Woman" AND "Parent"), how do i do it with getOWLClass()?, getOWLClass returns me a Class, i need the instances of the intersection of a class

Comment: You then have to create first the OWL class expression "Person and Woman and Parent", for this you can use getOWLObjectIntersectionOf. You give as parameters the OWLClasses (here the OWLClass objects) separated by a comma.

Comment: yes, thats what i did, but when I'm passing it to the reasoner to get the instances, its returning empty set

Comment: You need to pass all the types to the method `getOWLObjectIntersectionOf()`, not only "belgique" as you do now (first line of your question). It should look like: `getOWLObjectIntersectionOf(belgique, otherType, etc.)` then you use this `OWLClassExpression` to do the query.

Comment: I tried this as well, OWLClassExpression query = factory.getOWLObjectIntersectionOf(factory.getOWLClass("#belgique", pm),factory.getOWLClass("#celebration", pm));

Comment: I do have an individual in my ontology that is an instance of both "belgique" and "celebration"

Comment: have you tried to open your ontology with Protege http://protege.stanford.edu/ and do the query using the DL query tab? Do you get any results there?

Comment: yea, thats what i'm using, protege,